# Unity register by convention in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, unity-container

I can find a number of examples like the following but cannot figure out how to achieve this in vb.net

```
container
        .RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
            WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
            WithName.Default);
```

The equivalent code appears to require some parameters (implementation Type as Type) and I can't find any documentation anywhere about what's required.

Assuming this does what I think then my intention is to register all interfaces named 'I####Presenter' with the implementation '####Presenter'. So is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface` and `WithName.Default` are functions. `RegisterTypes` is expecting delegates. To pass a function as a delegate, you need to use the [AddressOf operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx) like this:

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
    AddressOf WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    AddressOf WithName.Default)
```